# selecting rows based on count from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `meetings` table, and `attendees` table.

I want to find meetings where `meetings.max_size` is either null OR the count of attendees for this meeting is less than `meetings.max_size`

I tried something like this, but i'm wondering if there is a better way

```
SELECT *
FROM meetings m
WHERE m.max_size is null 
OR (SELECT COUNT(*) from meeting_attendees ma where ma.meeting_id = m.id) < m.max_size
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. There are other ways, but I doubt them to be "better".

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
with cte as
(
select meeting_id,m.max_size,count(attandees_id) no_of_attendees
from meetings m join meeting_attendees ma on ma.meeting_id = m.id
group by meeting_id,m.max_size
)

select * from cte 
where max_size is null or no_of_attendees<max_size
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this is better then the original query. I find the original more readable and see no advantage in using yours.